# on localhost Only home page is working on wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, apache2

I have a WordPress website. This was working perfectly on xampp, but now I have migrated to lampp (Apache). Only home page is working now. Other pages are not found. Here is my htacces file code.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /website/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^unsubscribe/$ /website/wp-content/plugins/email-    newsletter/unsubscribe/unsubscribe.php [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /website/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: can you use admin area?

Comment: Yes, admin is accesible.

Comment: please check that wordpress has permission to write .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Could you please save permalink again?

**Step 1 :** Goto `wp-admin->setting->permalinks`

**Steps 2 :** After save changes

[image]

Comment: Could you please take backup of your `.htaccess` file then remove all code inside it after that save permalink?

Comment: Tried it too , it is saving all the httacees code, but pages still are not found. Pages works if i change my permalinks to plain.

Comment: please try with permalink `Post name`

Answer (score 0):

if you can use admin area, go to permalinks and update it.it will automatically fix .htacces file.

Also make sure the Apache module mod_rewrite is enabled on your local stack.

you also should update your site url in wp_config

reading these articles also can be helpful:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/only-my-front-page-works-all-my-permalinks-are-404

Answer (score 0):

**Update you permalinks again what you have alreade**
go Goto wp-admin->setting->permalinks
or you can try use bellow function

function change_permalinks() {
        global $wp_rewrite;
        $wp_rewrite->set_permalink_structure('/%postname%/');
        $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
    }
    add_action('init', 'change_permalinks');